# Wordpress How To Add Parent Page Type Slug To Post Type?

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I have post type with slug `post` that I can access via `https://<root>/post`.

I have page type with slug `page1` that I can access via `https://<root>/page1`.

I have page type with slug `page2` which has parent `page1` that I can access via `https://<root>/page1/page2`.

I modified the `post` parent to `page2`. But the problem is that I can't access the `post` via `https://<root>/page1/page2/post`.

I want to make the `post` permalink to include the parent slug `page2` so that it would be accessible via `https://<root>/page1/page2/post`.

How can I achieve that?